# How to properly Populate a Dropdown with SQL Query Values in React.Js Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

I have a react component called `Sidebar.jsx`. Within it, I am making an API call to get a array of fleets to populate an eventual JSX dropdown element within my Sidebar. This results in a simple JSON array.

I have imported a function called getFleets() from my services folder to make the API call. The service uses the `fetch` API to make a query call to my backend and looks like this:

```
export async function getFleets() {
    const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/fleets", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {},
        mode: 'cors'
    });
    return resp.json();
};
```

However, when I use the website, it appears to infinitely make the API call. This is my first time trying to make an API call within a react component so I am a bit confused here. Other guides I've read online seem to be similar but I am obviously missing something.

What can I do to make this API call only once and retrieve my JSON array such that I can later use it to populate the options in my return ?

`Sidebar.jsx`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getFleets } from "../services/FleetService";

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    const setFleets = async () => {
        const fleets = await getFleets();
        console.log(fleets);
        setData(fleets);
      }
    setFleets();
  }, [data]);


  return (
    <>
    // Add data to <select> </select>
  );
};
```

Comment: There are multiple libraries out there that accomplish async-selects. You might want to check them out if you don't require a custom implementation. for example: react-bootstrap-typeahead, react-select, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code works, since `data` is part of the dependency array sent to `useEffect`, every time `data` changes the effect runs, which changes `data`, which runs the effect again ...resulting in the infinite loop.

The simple fix is to remove `data` from the dependency array, and explicitly specifying an empty array `[]` as the second parameter of `useEffect`. This will make the effect run only exactly once, when the component is first rendered.

You need to explicitly specify an empty array because when the second parameter isn't specified at all, the effect will run on every render, bringing back the infinite loop issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. It definitely fixed the issue. I am still a little confused on why I am getting multiple console.log() results when I refresh my webpage. I don't understand why it is rendering multiple times. Maybe I don't quite understand what ```useState([]);``` is doing along with ```setData()```?

Comment: There should only be a single `console.log` call if the `useEffect(YOUR_FUNCTION, [])` call is done with `[]` as the second parameter, that shouldn't be the cause of the behavior you're describing. It's fine the way you're calling `useState` (with an empty array as the initial value). Maybe you have something like hot reloading enabled during development and that what's causing your component to get rendered multiple times (and therefore causing the effect to run multiple times)? Or maybe `console.log` is called in multiple places? (like inside of `getFleets`).